# Divide by zero error encountered when using window function sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When running the below query in SQL Server am getting an error:

> Divide by zero error encountered.

```
select ID, CID, PTYPE, GW,PPE
    , payPercentage = SUM(GW) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(GW)) OVER (partition by ID, PPE)
from pw_part
where ID ='001014055'
group by ID,CID,PPE,PTYPE,GW
```

`payPercentage=SUM(GW) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(GW)) OVER (partition by ID, PPE)` is causing the error

If I change SUM to

```
ISNULL (SUM(gross_wages) * 100.0 / NULLIF(SUM(SUM(gross_wages)),0),0) OVER (partition by ssn, pay_period_ending)) as pctg
```

I am facing the following error

> The function 'ISNULL' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Window function specification includes `over( partition by ... order by ... rows between ...)` and ends just after this last bracket. Place all this text in the first argument of `nullif`: `nullif(sum(..) over(...), 0)`

Comment: NULLIF(SUM(gw) * 100.0 / (SUM(SUM(gw)) OVER (partition by id, ppe)),0) as pctg - this is giving me "Divide by zero error encountered" error

Comment: No, you divide single summed wage by total. You need to `nullif` denominator, so `ifnull(sum(gw) / /*Should be NULLed for zero*/nullif(sum(sum(gw)) over(), 0), 0)`

Comment: It says - [ 'ifnull' is not a recognized built-in function name] -- am running this on sqlserver

Comment: NM... got it... it is IS NULL ... thank you for the help... this worked .... isnull(SUM(GW) * 100.0 / nullif(SUM(SUM(GW)) OVER (partition by ID, PPW), 0), 0)  as pctg

Comment: For sql server it is [`isnull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You need to reference the documentation first or google "sql server ifnull"

Answer (score 1):

You only need `nullif()` in the *denominator*:

```
SUM(GW) * 100.0 / NULLIF(SUM(SUM(GW)) OVER (partition by ID, PPE), 0) as percentage
```

In fact, you don't want `NULLIF()` in the *numerator* because that might return `NULL` values that should really be `0`.